# Showing products with angular in the html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make a table that shows products with angular, but the items are not showing up in HTML. If anyone notice anything wrong with the code, please help me.

This is my app.js:

```
(function (){
    var app = angular.module('confirmados', []);

    app.controler('ListaController', function (){
        this.product = gem;
    });

    var gem = {
        id: 1,
        name: 'cool',
        email: 'cool@'
    };
```

And this is my HTML:

```
                        <tr ng-controller="ListaController as lista" class="reservas">
                            <td> {{lista.product.id}} </td>
                            <td> {{lista.product.name}} </td>
                            <td> {{lista.product.email}} </td>
                        </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You spelled `controller` wrong:

```
app.controler
```

Should be

```
app.controller
```

Comment: lol.. what an idiot I was .. I searched for a typo but had not found